# How to define many to many relationships in laravel where pivot table has also many to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I have a database with four base tables: Classroom, Department, Subject and Day. A classroom is only available on certain days and on a day more than one classroom can be available. So this is a many to many relationship with the AvailableHour table (and model) as the pivot table. This table has two extra fields: available (true/false) and capacity (as capacity on a day can differ from the basecapacity).
To complicate things there is a second many to many relationship. If the classroom is available on a day it may only be allowed to certain departments with either all subjects, exclusive to one subject or one subject excluded. This is a second many to many relationship. A department can be part of many availableHours and an availableHour can have many departments.
See the included image.[image: database tables with relations]

How do I define this relationships in laravel in such a way that I can query which classrooms for an allowed department on a specified day are available?

Something like

`Classroom::with(['AvailableHours'=>where(day_id=requested_day and availabel=true),'AvailableHours.AllowDepartments'where(department_id=requested_department)])->get()`

(Closures are shortened for readabilty).
I started out with one to many relations, but this did not achieve the desired result. Converting them to many-many relationsships and pivot tables and models results in an error the moment I ask for `AvailableHours.AllowedDepartments`.

```
Call to undefined relationship [AllowdDepartments] on model [App\Day].
```

If I only use {Classroom::with('AvailableHours')} a collection is returned of classrooms. The property 'relations' has a value AvailableHours of array [1] whose single element is a collection of 'Day'.

Comment: What error do you get when you query for `AvailableHours.AllowedDepartments`?

Comment: I updated the question to include the error and some other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem without the use of many to many relationships, but by using one to many. The AllowedDpartments and AvailableHours tables get their own models
The Department model has many AllowedDapertments but an AllowedDepartment has only one Department. The same applies to the classrooms and AvailableHours, the Days and AvailableHours and lastly AvailableHours and AllowedDepartments. This results in the following relationsships:

```
class Day extends Model{
protected $guarded=[];

    public function availableHours(){
        return $this->hasMany(AvailableHour::class);
    }
}
```

.

```
class Classroom extends Model{
    public function availableHours()
    {
        //relationship with availableHour which determines the available hours
        return $this->hasMany(AvailableHour::class);
    }
}
```

.

```
class AvailableHour extends Model{

//get room this hour belongs to
    public function classroom() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class,'number');
    }

//get the day this hour belongs to
    public function day(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Day::class);
    }

//get all the allowedDepartments for this hour
    public function allowedDepartments(){
        return $this->hasMany(AllowedDepartment::class);
    }
}
```

.

```
class AllowedDepartment extends Model
{
    //get the availableHour this AllowedDepartment belongs to
    public function availableHour(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AvailableHour::class);
    }
// get the department this AllowedDepartment belongs to
    public function department(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
}
```

.

```
class Department extends Model{
//get all the allowedDepartments this Department has
    public function allowedDepartments(){
        return $this->hasMany(AllowedDepartment::class);
    }
}
```

The following query returns the classrooms that are available to the department in `$department`.

```
$classrooms=Classroom::whereHas('AvailableHours.AllowedDepartments.Department',function(Builder $query) use ($department){
        $query->where('id',$department->id);
    })->get('number')`
```